# nHibernate Cascade AllDeleteOrphan: Why is NH deleting each collection item individually

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

When I'm clearing a childcollection like this

```
table.Indizes.Clear();
session.Flush();
```

then NH generates a delete SQL for each item which was in the collection:

DELETE FROM x_inddef WHERE ind_name = 'IDX_ADRKONZ_CODE' AND tbl_name = 'ADRESSE' 
   DELETE FROM x_inddef WHERE ind_name = 'IDX_ADRKUND_EXT' AND tbl_name = 'ADRESSE'

...

Why isn't it generating a statement like this?

```
DELETE FROM x_inddef WHERE tbl_name = 'ADRESSE'
```

Is something wrong with my mappings, or is this just the normal behaviour?

Simplified Code with the fluent Mapping:

```
public class Table
{
    public virtual string Name {get;set;
    public virtual IList<Index> Indizes { get; set; }
}

public class TableOverride : IAutoMappingOverride<Table>
{
    public void Override(AutoMapping<Table> mapping)
    {
        mapping.Table("x_tables");
        mapping.Id(x => x.Name, "tbl_name");
        mapping.HasMany(x => x.Indizes).KeyColumn("tbl_name").Inverse().Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan();
    }
}

public class Index
{
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual Table Table { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        //...
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        //...
    }
}

public class IndexOverride : IAutoMappingOverride<Index>
{
    public void Override(AutoMapping<Index> mapping)
    {
        mapping.Table("x_inddef");
        mapping.CompositeId().
            KeyProperty(x => x.Name, "ind_name").
            KeyReference(x => x.Table, "tbl_name");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should enable batch updates option with nhibernate

First of all set `adonet.batch_size` property in your NHibernate configuration to value, greater then zero.

And then mark each hasMany collection with `.BatchSize(xxx)`

```
mapping.HasMany(x => x.Indizes)
   .BatchSize(25)
   .KeyColumn("tbl_name")
   .Inverse()
   .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan();
```

I guess this should help

Comment: This is probably the best option if you want to keep things easy..at the very least, you'll avoid several round-trips for the individual deletes.

Comment: Ok, with an increased batch_size the performance issue is solved. It works without marking every collection with .BatchSize.

Answer (score 1):

One-shot deletes do not work with inverse=true. Allocating a new instance of the index collection with 0 elements and dereferencing the old one throws an exception as Nhibernate expects to manage the collection. It seems the only way out is to use hql.

Check section 19.5.4 in the documentation - http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html

Comment: From the docs you are linking: "one-shot-delete apply to collections mapped inverse="true"." which is contradictory to what you say.

Comment: Hibernate docs: One-shot-delete does not apply to collections mapped inverse="true"; NHibernate docs: one-shot-delete apply to collections mapped inverse="true"... maybe the nhibernate documentation is wrong...

Comment: If I'm dereferencing the collection, nhibernate throws an exception "A collection with cascade="all-delete-orphan" was no longer referenced"

Comment: Yes, it doesn't allow dereferencing. nhibernate expects to manage the collections. Tried some variations but no luck

Answer (score 0):

`All-delete-orphan` means that your child collection would be deleted if you delete the parent element.
meaning- if you delete a `Table` object, than `DELETE FROM x_inddef WHERE tbl_name =...` would be issued.
calling `Clear()` is just a shorthand for deleting all the objects in a collection, but the `Table` object itself remains intact.

Comment: even when i'm deleting the Table object, the child objects are still deleted one by one...

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution is to use HQL:

```
session.CreateQuery("DELETE Index i WHERE i.Table.Name = :tblName")
    .SetString( "tblName", "MyTable" )
    .ExecuteUpdate();
```